# When inserting a FAT32 memory card why does Time Machine add "Untitled" to every APFS snapshot?

Tags: time-machine

I am changing the question, since the original has a decent explanation that predates my question, and I don't want to lose the intriguing comment from @benwiggy below which led me to ask this question.

To test @benwiggy's conjecture I inserted a FAT32 formatted memory card titled "DR-40" into my iMac tonight and then ran Time Machine. A new Folder is created on the Time Machine backups volume, but not just for the current snapshot - it's created for every snapshot and it's called "Untitled" not "DR-40", and empty *(A lot of clutter and potentially confusing in a years time)*.

[image]

[image]

If I then exclude that same memory card from Time Machine backups by adding it to "Exclude From Backups" and re-running Time Machine backup - it is not removed, it remains. Not only that but even if I eject "DR-40" and run Time Machine with it remaining in the exclude list the new snapshot also contains "Untitled".

[image]

**This begs the question how does Time Machine keep track of volumes that are attached so it knows whether they have been excluded or not? Is it by volume name or UUID or some other method?**

Comment: If you exclude the drives from the backup, that should remove the backups of those drives. (Or it used to...!)

Comment: @benwiggy Do you know if it's by UUID of the volume or by volume name that the drives are recognized? Wondering if a name is changed if TM can still recognize which one it is.